# Show that $f_{n}(x):=nx(1-x)^{n}$ is uniformly bounded on $[0,1]$ for all $n\geq 1$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, proof-explanation

Consider $f_{n}(x):=nx(1-x)^{n}$ defined for $n=1,2,3,\cdots$ and $x\in [0,1]$. The exercises have two parts:

> (a) Show that for each $n$, $f_{n}(x)$ has a unique maximum $M_{n}$ at $x=x_{n}$. Compute the limit of $M_{n}$ and $x_{n}$ as $n\rightarrow\infty.$
>
> (b) Prove that $f_{n}(x)$ is uniformly bounded in $[0,1]$.

---

I have computed that for each $n$, $f_{n}(x)$ has a unique maximum in $[0,1]$ at $$x_{n}=\dfrac{1}{1+n}$$ with the maximum value $$M_{n}=\Big(\dfrac{n}{n+1}\Big)^{n+1}.$$  Thus $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_{n}=0\ \ \ \text{and}\ \ \ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}M_{n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\Big(1-\dfrac{1}{1+n}\Big)^{n+1}=e^{-1}.$$

---

The solution says that since $|f_{n}(x)|\leq |M_{n}|$ for each $n=1,2,\cdots$, the above shows that $|f_{n}(x)|\leq e^{-1}$ for all $x\in [0,1]$ and $n=1,2,\cdots$.

I don't understand this. To show the uniform boundedness, don't we need to show $$\sup_{n}|f_{n}(x)|\leq C,\ \ \text{for some constant}\  C\ \text{and for all}\  x\in [0,1]?$$

It is true that since $|f_{n}(x)|\leq M_{n}$ for each $n$ and for all $x\in [0,1]$, we have $$\sup_{n}|f_{n}(x)|\leq\sup_{n}|M_{n}|,$$ but why does the limit of $M_{n}$ being $e^{-1}$ implies the sup is $e^{-1}$?

Thank you!

Comment: $M_n$ is increasing.

Comment: Is $(1/1-(n+1))^(n+1)$ a monotone increasing sequence as $n$ is taken $n=1,2,3,\cdots$? If so that should be easily checked, and I *think* would imply what you want,

Comment: If you just want a uniform bound, and do not care about the precise value of the bound, then the convergence of $M_n$ already tells it: $M_n$ converges $\implies |M_n| \leq C$ for some $C > 0$. You said that the upper bound could be $e^{-1}$, I guess you could check if $M_n$ is monotone.

Comment: @RRL I am actually also suspecting it is increasing, let me check.

Comment: @coffeemath yeah. I am suspecting so, I will check! Thank you!

Comment: @mathdoge so what is the difference between uniform boundedness and boundedness? What you are saying is that since  $M_{n}$ is convergent, it is bounded. So I should actually show $\sup_{x\in [0,1]}|f_{n}(x)|\leq C$ for some $C$?  since I don't think $|M_{n}|\leq C$ implies $\sup_{n}|M_{n}|\leq C$.

Comment: I don't think $M_n$ converging is sufficient. You would also need to show that it is non-decreasing. @mathdoge

Comment: @Enforce yeah. I am suspecting so. By the way, is my idea correct? to show $\sup_{n}|f_{n}(x)|\leq C$ for all $x\in[0,1]$? Thanks!

Comment: $|M_n| \leq C$ for all $n$ then certainly $\sup_n |M_n| \leq C$.

Comment: @mathdoge ah yeah. Sorry. I got confused. so basically for a real sequence which only depends on $n$, the uniform boundedness is the same as being bounded?

Comment: @JacobsonRadical I think uniform boundedness is for sequence of functions, and we don't use this term for a classical sequence.

Comment: @mathdoge you are right. thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is well known that $(1 + 1/n)^n \nearrow e$ and $(1+1/n)^{n+1} \searrow e.$ See one of the many proofs on this site [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2071492/148510).

Thus, $M_n = \left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n+1} = \frac{1}{(1+1/n)^{n+1}} \nearrow e^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\log(M_n) = (n+1)\log\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)$$

And also

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left((x+1)\log\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)\right) = \log\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)+ \frac{1}{x}.$$

Since

\begin{align*}\frac{x}{x+1}e^{1/x} &= \frac{x}{x+1}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\frac{1}{x})^n}{n!} \\ 
&= \frac{x}{x+1}(1+1/x+1/2x^2+\ldots) \\
&=\frac{x}{x+1} + \frac{1}{x+1} + \frac{1}{2x(x+1)}+\ldots \\
& = 1 +  \frac{1}{2x(x+1)}+\ldots > 1, \end{align*}

so we must have that $\log\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)+ \frac{1}{x} > 0$, i.e. $M_n$ is increasing so $f_n$ is uniformly bounded by $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}M_n = 1/e$. Of course we are assuming $ x > 0$, but that is not a problem here.